# Cordova plugin push notification not working?

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification

I am new in Cordova and I want to use cordova Push Notification. Can anyone help me to use the plugin. It shows an error :

```
Error: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/zckrs/cordova-plugin-android-support-v4.git via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm WARN package.json helloworld@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json helloworld@1.0.0 No README data
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit at getNotFoundError (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:14:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit at F (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:69:19)
npm WARN addRemoteGit at E (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:81:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:90:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\index.js:44:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:29:5

npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
npm ERR! code ENOGIT

npm ERR! not found: git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! D:\ExerciseApp\node_modules\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push).

`https://github.com/zckrs/cordova-plugin-android-support-v4.git` is a plugin to add Android Support v4 client library not Push Notifications.

You can add the `phonegap-plugin-push` by typing the following in cmd -

```
cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push
```

or

```
 cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push
```

Quick Example -

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
    function onDeviceReady(){

       var push = PushNotification.init({ "android": {"senderID": "91254247XXXX"}}); //add your sender ID from Firebase Cloud Messenging

       push.on('registration', function(data) {
           console.log(data.registrationId);
           //document.getElementById("gcm_id").innerHTML = data.registrationId;
       });

       push.on('notification', function(data) {

           alert("On Notification function!!");
             // data.message,
            // data.title,
            // data.count,
            // data.sound,
            // data.image,
            // data.additionalData
            console.log("notification event");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
           //Do something 
       });

       push.on('error', function(e) {
           alert(e);
       });
    }
```

***Note*** - You need to add your app to [Firebase Cloud Messenging](https://console.firebase.google.com) for android platform and get your Sender ID from `Firebase Console->Setting->Cloud Messenging Tab`.